# Behaviours in wpf apps Microsoft expression blend 4

Tags: wpf, expression-blend-4

I am using Microsoft expression blend 4 and i want to add a simple button,in a wpf application, which by clicking it(on "Run Project" mode) navigates the user to another existing wpf application in expression blend 4.This can be done by using a method but maybe I used the wrong method or i used the right method the wrong way.To be more specific i dragged on the button(that i want to make the task i mentioned) the "Launch UriOrFile Action" method but i realised(by making experiments with various files on desktop and using internet url's) that i can only link the running wpf application with random files or internet sites and not to another wpf application as i wanted(when i put the path of the wpf application it pops up a window saying"windows explorer has stopped working",something that didnt occured when i put random file's paths or internet sites url's).If anyone understands my problem let me know!thanks!!

Comment: To get help you are going to need to supply more details than that... what have you tried? What result are you getting? Is there an exception? Take a moment to read the help topic [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks!

Comment: @slugster maybe you are right i'll try to make my question more specific thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Create a command that fires code that calls that method.

Comment: seems to be a good solution.the start method might have to be downloaded right?i can't see it in the existing ones.

Comment: The `Process` class is available in the `System` assembly under the namespace `System.Diagnostics` so make sure you have the correct references and namespaces. Also make sure it is available in your target framework, of which I don't know for you.